# How to test the multicollinearity using r

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial

I'am trying to do a `multinomial logistic regression` with categorical dependent variable using r, so before starting the logistic regression 
I want to check `multicollinearity` with all independents variables expressed as `dichotomous` and `ordinal`.

so how to test the `multicollinearity` in r ?

Can someone help me please.

Comment: have u tried `vif` function from the `car` package?

Comment: So I do the logistic regression at first then i check the multicollineairty ?

Comment: It is one possibility. Usually collinearity problems would also be indicated by inflated standard errors of (some) coefficients in the `summary` output of the model. Not sure if `vif` function deals correctly with categorical variables

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

```
library(HH)

model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + qsec, mtcars)
vif(model)
```

Comment: Didn't manage to install `HH` library on ubuntu mashine as `HH` needs a tone of extra packages + external libraries. The example is for linear model whereas question was regarding multinomial model

Comment: also, what do you need `HH` library for? Does it contain a different `vif` implementation compared to `car` package?

Comment: I'm on Windows and works like a charm for me. Never used the `car` implementation so I can't tell. This one worked for me just fine.